Pytesseract improving number recognition using CV
i'm using Pytesseract to screenshot parts of my screen and then using cv2 to edit this image into black letters with white background, however i'm getting the exact opposite and cant figure out why.
THIS IS HOW I'M DEFYING CV2:
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(grey, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return binary

def take_screenshot_and_preprocess(x1, y1, x2, y2, config=None):
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1))
    screenshot_path = "screenshot.png"
    screenshot.save(screenshot_path)
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(screenshot_path)
    return preprocessed_image

    def extract_text_from_image(preprocessed_image, config=None):
    cv2.imwrite("preprocessed_image.png", preprocessed_image)
    preprocessed_pil_image= Image.open("preprocessed_image.png")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_pil_image)
    return text

AND THIS IS HOW I'M CALLING THE FUNCTION:
preprocessed_image = take_screenshot_and_preprocess(402, 208, 480, 225,) #screenshot payment
text = extract_text_from_image(preprocessed_image, config='--oem 3')                           
pyautogui.typewrite(text)

Original screenshot:
Processed screenshot:
Number detected by the code on the original screenshot: 1.31218
i tried to invert the values for CV2, force inv binary but none did anything

all those operations are wasted effort. the path from your first to your second picture is a simple inversion. -- what do you mean, you get the "opposite" when "inverting"? isn't that expected?

i get the black background with white letters regardless of using inversion or not


Read the docs: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md
Adjust image according docs:

Resize image to meet optimal letter size
Remove non text pixels/proper cropped image
Binarize/threshold image




tesseract resized_treshholded.png - --psm 6
1.312,18

